# Extracting seasonal effect without using stl or decompose

Tags: r, stl

I have a data named 'bicoal' which consists of annual bituminous coal production in the United States from 1920 to 1968.

```
`Time Series:
Start = 1920 

End = 1968 

Frequency = 1 
 
[1] 569 416 422 565 484 520 573 518 501 505 468 382 310 334 359 372 439 446 349 395
[21] 461 511 583 590 620 578 534 631 600 438 516 534 467 457 392 467 500 493 410 412
[41] 416 403 422 459 467 512 534 552 545`
```

I made a time series, saved under the name `time_series`, and wanted to extract the seasonal effect using the code `plot(decompose(time_series))` and `plot(stl(time_series))`, but got an error message

```
Error in stl(time_series) : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
Error in decompose(time_series) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

If stl nor decompose doesn't work, is there a way to extract the seasonal effect?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your time series is constructed I think this might be your problem.

```
data <- rep(seq(1,5),5)
ts.1 <- ts(data)
stl(ts.1)
```

[image]

Now to fix this issue the `ts` function has a frequency argument that defines the period of the data.

```
ts.2 <- ts(data, frequency = 5)

stl(ts.2, s.window = "periodic")
```

[image]

Comment: Will this affect the graph shape in some way (e.g. more peaks compared to annual data)?

Comment: With annual data it is hard to determine a clear seasonal pattern. With monthly data it is easy since the pattern would expect to repeat every year. I recommend looking at the autocorrelation of your data to see what lags have high autocorrelation. For example in my `data <- rep(seq(1,5),5)`  running `acf(data)` we see very high autocorrelation with lag 5 since the data repeats every 5. @rrr

Comment: Running a simple linear regression with just a time variable will tell you if there is a trend in your data. And check your residuals with a Durbin Watson test to see if there is  any more autocorrelation. If there is there might be a seasonal effect which you can examine further with the `acf` function then you might consider a autoregressive model with lag whatever the high autocorrelation is.  The lag variable in your autoregressive model might be your seasonal effect your interested in.